# How I get the user_id value in sfDoctrineGuard plugin?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

I'm working on one module based on sfGuard and I need to allow users to edit or delete records. This is how I get the users:

```
$id_empresa = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getSfGuardUserProfile()->getIdempresa();
$this->users = Doctrine_Core::getTable('sfGuardUser')->createQuery('u')->leftJoin('u.SfGuardUserProfile p')->where('idempresa = ?', $id_empresa)->execute();
```

But then in the view while I'm iterating I don't know how to access to `user_id` value. I checked `BasesfGuardUser` but no method for get the Id exists, any advice or help?

**Added the code for the view**
This is the code for the iteration:

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $user->getFirstName() ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $user->getLastName() ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $user->getEmailAddress() ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $user->getUsername() ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $user->getIsActive() ?></td>
       <td>
          <a href="<?php echo url_for('guard/users/' . $user->get('id') . '/edit') ?>" class="btn btn-success btn-mini">Editar</a>
          <a href="<?php echo url_for('guard/users/' . $user->get('id')) ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini">Eliminar</a>
       </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: `foreach ($users as $user) var_dump($user->get('id'))`

Comment: @1ed, nope, doesn't work

Comment: that should work (maybe `idempresa` is the name of the id coloumn?), but try `$user->getPrimaryKey()` then... and if you want to generate URLs you should use the route name and the object as parameter like `url_for('sf_gaurd_user_edit', $user);`. `php symfony app:routes backend` to see available routes

Comment: @1ed ups apologies man, both works I mean the first solution you leave and the second one based on `getPrimaryKey()`, the problem is here: `<a href="<?php echo url_for('usuarios/edit/' . $user->get('id') ) ?>" class="btn btn-success btn-mini">Editar</a>` why the value isn't append to the URL?

Comment: No worries :)... I added an answer where I try to explain the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `'guard/users/' . $user->get('id') . '/edit'` part in `url_for`. Maybe it's because `usuarios/edit/1` is not a valid parameter for `url_for` so it's parsed as `module/action` and the `/1` part is ignored, but I'm not sure.

IIRC `url_for` actually has 4 valid form:

- `url_for('module/action', array('param1' => 'value1'), true /* absolute */)`
- `url_for('@route_name?param1=value1', true /* absolute */)`
- `url_for('route_name', array('param1' => 'value1'), true /* absolute */)`
- this is for object routes only: `url_for('route_name', $object, true /* absolute */)` or `url_for('route_name', array('sf_subject' => $object, 'extra_param' => 'value'), true /* absolute */)`

If you have an object route (e.g. `sfDoctrineRoute`) you should use the last one, if you have a non-object route with parameters you should use the 3rd and if you have a route with no parameter you should use the 2nd.

Comment: thanks, I figure out how to deal with this and get things done